# Cosmos does not respond to a request from Cygnus located on a fiware private instance

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus, fiware-cosmos

[Click here for problem description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVDfr.png)

This question derives from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674713/cygnus-can-not-persist-data-on-cosmos-global-instance) other one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cygnus can not persist data on Cosmos global instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674713/cygnus-can-not-persist-data-on-cosmos-global-instance)