# Connectivity problems between FILAB VMs and Cosmos global instance

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus, fiware-cosmos

I have the same kind of connectivity problem discussed in the question ["Cygnus can not persist data on Cosmos global instance"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674713/cygnus-can-not-persist-data-on-cosmos-global-instance). However, I have found no solution after read it.

Nowadays, I have recently deployed two virtual machines in FILAB (both VMs contain Orion ContextBroker 0.26.1 and Cygnus 0.11.0).

When I try to persist data on Cosmos via Cygnus, I get the following error message (the same in both VMs) :

```
2015-12-17 19:03:00,221 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor)     
[ERROR - com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionSink.process(OrionSink.java:305)]
 Persistence error (The /user/rmartinezcarreras/def_serv/def_serv_path/room1_room     
directory could not be created in HDFS. Server response: 503 Service unavailable)
```

On the other hand, when I try to fire a request from the command line of whatever VM, I get the next response:

```
[root@orionlarge centos]# curl -v -X GET "http://cosmos.lab.fiware.org:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/rmartinezcarreras/?       
op=liststatus&user.name=rmartinezcarreras" -H "X-Auth-Token: XXXXXXX"
* About to connect() to cosmos.lab.fiware.org port 14000 (#0)
*   Trying 130.206.80.46... connected
* Connected to cosmos.lab.fiware.org (130.206.80.46) port 14000 (#0)
> GET /webhdfs/v1/user/rmartinezcarreras/?    
op=liststatus&user.name=rmartinezcarreras HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7     
NSS/3.16.2.3 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: cosmos.lab.fiware.org:14000
> Accept: */*
> X-Auth-Token: XXXXX
>
* Closing connection #0
* Failure when receiving data from the peer
curl: (56) Failure when receiving data from the peer
```

Nevertheless, from an external VM (outside FILAB):

```
[root@dsieBroker orion]# curl -v -X GET     
"http://cosmos.lab.fiware.org:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/rmartinezcarreras/?   
op=liststatus&user.name=rmartinezcarreras" -H "X-Auth-Token: XXXXX"
* About to connect() to cosmos.lab.fiware.org port 14000 (#0)
*   Trying 130.206.80.46... connected
* Connected to cosmos.lab.fiware.org (130.206.80.46) port 14000 (#0)
> GET /webhdfs/v1/user/rmartinezcarreras/?   
op=liststatus&user.name=rmartinezcarreras HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7    
NSS/3.19.1 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: cosmos.lab.fiware.org:14000
> Accept: */*
> X-Auth-Token: XXXXXX
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: HEAD, POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, content-type, X-Auth-Token, Tenant-    
ID, Authorization
< server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< set-cookie:
hadoop.auth="u=rmartinezcarreras&p=rmartinezcarreras&t=simple&e=XXXXXX&s=
XXXXhD    8="; Version=1; Path=/
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< transfer-encoding: chunked
< date: Thu, 17 Dec 2015 18:52:46 GMT
< connection: close
< Content-Length: 243
< ETag: W/"f3-NL9+bYJLweyFpoJfNgjQrg"
< 
{"FileStatuses":{"FileStatus":       
[{"pathSuffix":"def_serv","type":"DIRECTORY","length":0,"owner":
"rmartinezcarreras","group":"rmartinezcarreras","permission":"740",
"accessTime":0,"modificationTime":1450349251833,"blockSize":0,
"replication":0}]}}
* Closing connection #0
```

Also get good results from my Cosmos account.

How can I solve this? It seems a connectivity problem. Could you help me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: As with the other issue you are commenting, I'll pass the ball to the network people since this is clearly a connectivity problem.

Comment: Network people tell me this should be fixed.

Comment: I have just done another test and I still can't connect to Cosmos global instance from FILAB. The response is similar to trace 2 above (...Failure when receiving data from the peer at the end).                                                   If the connectivity issues are solved, what could cause this communication problem FILAB-COSMOS?

Comment: Something is wrong in the FILAB VMs because with the same Cygnus settings on a machine outside FILAB, I can persist data in Cosmos.

Comment: Yes, I've passed the ball to the network people again. Sorry :(

Comment: Today I have performed the test since my Cosmos account . Still does not work:

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this was a problem with the OAuth2 proxy we are using for Authentication and Authorization. The underlying `Express` module it is based was adding a `content-length` header when another `transfer-encoding: chunked` header was present. As researched in this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34923325/why-is-my-curl-command-sending-a-reset), this combination is not according to the [RFC](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4), and was causing certain fully compliant client implementations were reseting the connection.