# Why is my curl command sending a reset?

Tags: curl

I'm trying the following one:

```
$ curl -X GET "http://somewhere:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/frb?op=liststatus&user.name=frb" -H "X-Auth-Token: xxxxxxxx"
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

At first stage, I though this was a problem with the server, but sniffing the traffic on the remote side I found the reset was sent by `curl`! Why?

[image]

Some useful information:

```
$ curl --version
curl 7.29.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.29.0 NSS/3.19.1 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.28 libssh2/1.4.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz 

$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)

$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Any idea about what is happening? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1**

As suggested by @nos, I'm including the detail about the `content-length` header and the actual payload length sent:

[image]

Interesting, it seems there is something incorrect there...

**EDIT 2**

Printing the whole Http response. The first chunk is delared to be 1829 bytes length (725 hexadecimal), but counting the payload (without the final `\r\n`) it gives 1828 bytes length; by adding `\r\n` the count is 1830 bytes length. In both cases it seems it differs from the declared length in the `content-length` header.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: HEAD, POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, content-type, X-Auth-Token, Tenant-ID, Authorization
server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
set-cookie: hadoop.auth="u=frb&p=frb&t=simple&e=1453410695487&s=YUl/hzzvVQ27/n4yeyi8ZL3r7K8="; Version=1; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 21-Jan-2016 21:11:35 GMT; HttpOnly
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
transfer-encoding: chunked
date: Thu, 21 Jan 2016 11:11:35 GMT
connection: close
Content-Length: 1829
ETag: W/"725-zwbM26xiKZvcP52NTX57Pg"

725
{"FileStatuses":{"FileStatus":[{"pathSuffix":".Trash","type":"DIRECTORY","length":0,"owner":"frb","group":"frb","permission":"700","accessTime":0,"modificationTime":1437696000073,"blockSize":0,"replication":0},{"pathSuffix":"def_serv","type":"DIRECTORY","length":0,"owner":"frb","group":"frb","permission":"755","accessTime":0,"modificationTime":1453133134503,"blockSize":0,"replication":0},{"pathSuffix":"hivetest","type":"DIRECTORY","length":0,"owner":"frb","group":"frb","permission":"755","accessTime":0,"modificationTime":1437667486016,"blockSize":0,"replication":0},{"pathSuffix":"mrtest","type":"DIRECTORY","length":0,"owner":"frb","group":"frb","permission":"755","accessTime":0,"modificationTime":1437647900960,"blockSize":0,"replication":0},{"pathSuffix":"mrtestoutput","type":"DIRECTORY","length":0,"owner":"frb","group":"frb","permission":"755","accessTime":0,"modificationTime":1437672805148,"blockSize":0,"replication":0},{"pathSuffix":"prueba1","type":"DIRECTORY","length":0,"owner":"frb","group":"frb","permission":"755","accessTime":0,"modificationTime":1453374021476,"blockSize":0,"replication":0},{"pathSuffix":"serv1","type":"DIRECTORY","length":0,"owner":"frb","group":"frb","permission":"755","accessTime":0,"modificationTime":1453301564320,"blockSize":0,"replication":0},{"pathSuffix":"test","type":"DIRECTORY","length":0,"owner":"frb","group":"frb","permission":"755","accessTime":0,"modificationTime":1453301887369,"blockSize":0,"replication":0},{"pathSuffix":"test2","type":"DIRECTORY","length":0,"owner":"frb","group":"frb","permission":"755","accessTime":0,"modificationTime":1453369175937,"blockSize":0,"replication":0},{"pathSuffix":"vaya","type":"DIRECTORY","length":0,"owner":"frb","group":"frb","permission":"755","accessTime":0,"modificationTime":1453369690198,"blockSize":0,"replication":0}]}}

0
```

**EDIT 3**

I've tried with another client machine... and it works! In this case, the server continues sending both `content-lenght` and `transfer-encoding=chunked`, but it is considered OK by `curl` and no RESET is sent back. `curl` version is different:

```
$ curl --version
curl 7.43.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0) libcurl/7.43.0 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.5
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz UnixSockets
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did the server send the complete response before the FIN packet is sent ? You'll need to verify this by looking at the Content-Length header in the response compared to how many bytes there actually are in the content.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Please, see my edit, I've added the detail about the `content-length` header. It seems there is something incorrect there... I've found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304126/chunked-encoding-and-content-length-header) other related SOF question, but do not know if that's the reason the client (`curl`) is sending the reset.

Comment: `content-length : 1829\r\n`? Hmm, I see other `\r\n`s listed too. Are you running this on Windows?

Comment: Both client and server are running in CentOS machines.

Comment: @shellter: HTTP uses `\r\n` line separators for header fields. That's correct here.

Comment: @DarkDust : Thanks for the info, I'll try to file that away for future reference ;-) ! Good luck to all.

Comment: @frb Did you count that the http body actually has 1829 bytes ? curl is giving you an error either because the body has less bytes than that before the server closes the connection, or because the response contains a content-length header but also uses chunked encoding in the response body, and that combination is something you are not supposed to do according to the http protocol (which is what wireshark is also telling you)

Comment: @nos, please, see my second edit. The first chunk is declared to be 1829 bytes length (725 hexadecimal), but counting the payload (without the final `\r\n`) it gives 1828 bytes length; by adding `\r\n` the count is 1830 bytes length. In both cases it seems it differs from the declared length in the `content-length` header. Anyway, should not be discarded the `content-length` is the transfer encoding is `chunked`? ([reference](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4))

Comment: @frb Yes, the Content-Length header should not be there when the content is chunked, so certainly your server is doing stuff it should not do.

Comment: I've tried with another client machine and... now it works! (please, see my edit 3). I've seen the `curl` version is different (a recent one), so I'm starting to think that modern versions of `curl` relax the checks.

Comment: So @nos, you were totally right, and after fixing the server side it is working like a charm. If you post the answer, I'll be glad to vote for it :) Thanks!